# How to get Independent Left/Right channel Delay in FMOD using 2D Stereo Mp3 files?

Tags: audio, media-player, fmod, directsound, xaudio2

I am trying to set the delay of left and right channels of the input MP3 file independently before playback. I want to play the left channel at say a delay of 2ms and the right channel at the delay of say 10ms, so the overall delay between channels would be of 8ms, instead of the 0ms delay between left and right channels of the Mp3 audio.

Some example Code of what I’m testing –

```
result = system->createStream(“C:/1.mp3”, FMOD_2D , NULL, &sound1);
errChk(result);
result = system->playSound(sound1, 0, true, &channel1);
errChk(result);
```

Here, I only have one channel where the sound plays, although it does playback in stereo with separate channels, so how do I delay the actual channels being played back?

Is that possible to do so with FMOD? Can someone point me to some code or reference that I can use? Thank you very much!